# Calculate the residue of $f(z) = \frac {e^{-z}} {(z+2)^3} $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

I'm currently studying integral solving methods using the Residue Theorem. However, I sometimes have problems finding a way to calculate the residue(s). For example, what do I do when a function includes the exponential function (or any other function whose Taylor series is commonly known)?

After a while, I found a solution that I added below this question. In general, I thought that it might be helpful to others when they are dealing with solving integrals using the residue theorem for functions that involve the exponential function (or any variants of it).

My initial problem was:

How do I calculate the residue of $f(z) = \frac {e^{-z}} {(z+2)^3} $ at $z = -2 ?$

With the solution to this problem, I was then able to calculate the integral using the residue theorem:
$$
\int_{|z|=3} f(z) dz =  ?
$$

Comment: I appreciate the fact you wrote a solution, but it will be helpful if you edit your post with details of your background, if you are currently reading any book, and where you found this question. We can think of reopening the question if you undertake these actions, but I'm happy with your self-answer.

Comment: I added some more information about why I stumbled into this kind of problem. In general, I thought that it might be helpful to others when they are dealing with solving integrals using the residue theorem for functions that involve the exponential function (or any variants of it).

Comment: Kindly edit this comment into the post above, and we can try to reopen the question. I would suggest you add an example of a similar question you solved using the residue theorem. I am then happy with this post, already quite good to be fair.

Comment: I now gave my best to comply with your recommendations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. I have even up voted your question in this regard. I hope we see more good content from you on the site in the future, hopefully something which doesn't get closed at least!

Comment: @simonovic If one of the two answers solves your problem entirely or was the most helpful you might want to "accept the answer" by clicking at the check mark next to the answer. It will then indicate to other users that your question/problem/etc. has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a fair solution. Other than that you could also calculate the residue as follows:
We have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res}_{-2}f = \frac{1}{(3-1)!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}z^2}\left((z+2)^3\cdot f(z)\right)\bigg|_{z = -2},
\end{align}
since we have a pole of order $3$ at $z = -2$. Due to
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(3-1)!}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}z^2}\left((z+2)^3\cdot f(z)\right) = \frac{1}{2!}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}z^2} e^{-z} = \frac{e^{-z}}{2},
\end{align}
we find
\begin{align}
\boxed{\operatorname{Res}_{-2}f = \frac{e^{2}}{2}.}
\end{align}

**Edit:**

Here I used the general formula

\begin{align}
c_{-1} = \operatorname{Res}_af = \frac{1}{(k-1)!}\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}^{k-1}}{\mathrm{d}z^{k-1}}\left((z-a)^k\cdot f(z) \right) \bigg|_{z=a},
\end{align}
if $a$ is a pole of order $k$ of $f$.
What this formula does is basically extracting the coefficient $c_{-1}$ of the Laurent series which by definition is your residue.

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm fairly new to residue calculation, I had a lot of trouble with this one. After a while, I found a neat solution  that I'd like to share.
We have
$$\begin{align}
f(z) &= \frac {e^{-z}} {(z+2)^3} = \frac{1}{(z+2)^3} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-z)^k}{k!} \\
&= \frac{1}{(z+2)^3} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}(z+2)^k e^2,
\end{align}$$
since
$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}(z+2)^k = e^{-z-2}.
$
Thus we get
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{(z+2)^3} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}(z+2)^k e^2 = e^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}(z+2)^{k-3}
$$
and the residue would be $\frac{e^2}{2}.$